# Node express. Routes db.get and find method

Tags: express

Here is my routes/users.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/*
 * GET userlist.
 */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('userlist');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In this code, what is the req object? And when we call req.db... that's made available to us via this right in app.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest2');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
```

What is the app.use exactly doing here?

Comment: You're looking for the Express (and Monk) documentation.

Comment: You can start to answer your questions here: http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: `app.use` defines some middleware...so each request, it hits that `use` function - assigns `req.db`, then proceeds as normal. `db` is equal to `monk('localhost:27017/nodetest2');`